# Расширение для VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015

какие расширение скачать для того что бы отображалось файл jpg на редакторе vs code ?.
*и я хотел уточнить что нужно именно в одном окне отображалось а не в раздельном*
*не обращайте внимание на что я открываю юпитеровский файл на vs code просто мне так удобно*
[image: скрин для подробности]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я хотел что бы jpg файл отображалось вместе с кодом что бы я мог понять задачу в целом
*просто нужно чтоб мне было видно jpg файл не как тут а полноценно с картинками*